# The question is about localhost, Swift URL, NetBeans and Xampp

Tags: ios, url, localhost

everyone, I have a question to ask about "localhost"

I am a newbie and use NetBeans and Xampp as DATABASE to connect with Swift.

I use "http://localhost/" as my URL on the simulator of Mac, which works fine.

But when I change to my physical device, it has an error " can not connect to the server", how can I solve this problem?

And another question, if one day I publish the APP, what URL should I use? Is it still "http://localhost/" or anything else?  I am really confused, can someone give me some advice? I would really appreciate!

Comment: "localhost" is whatever device the code is running on. So no, you can't use `localhost` to reach a URL on another device.

Answer (score 1):

localhost is 127.0.0.1 address, used only in current machine.
When you using simulator, simulator run in same machine with server, it will success access 127.0.0.1 address.
If you using real device, please find your server ip with command `ifconfig` and use that in App.
Hope to help you.

Answer (score 0):

As was written in the comments, http://localhost/ only works on the current device (similar if you are using http://127.0.0.1). The simulator is running on your Mac, so it will work.

Since the physical device is not on your Mac, it will not work. So, for testing, you might want to set up a test server on your computer or on another machine. Then, you would replace the URL with the IP address or hostname of the server. For production, you would need to set up a server or find a hosting service. Then, you would use the URL for whatever server you go with in your app instead of http://localhost/.

Comment: `localhost` is `127.0.0.1` so they are the same thing, not just similar.